# 301 Redirect and HTTPS

Tags: redirect, https

OK, please go gentle on me as I am a bit of a beginner when it comes to domains.

My old website was hosted by Squarespace and the Domain provided by GoDaddy and was set up to use SSL (by ticking that option within the Squarespace settings). For this example, let's say the domain was myoldsite.co.uk
This site is now closed down and no longer active on Squarespace.

All of my backlinks over the last 3 years have been created for https://myoldsite.co.uk

Recently, I have created a new Wordpress site again using SSL using the domain name: https://mynewsite.co.uk

Within the GoDaddy admin console for myoldsite.co.uk, I have created a 301 redirect going to https://mynewsite.co.uk

This is working well when I enter http://myoldsite.co.uk, I am forwarded to https://mynewsite.co.uk

However, when I enter https://myoldsite.co.uk, nothing happens and I am not forwarded.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is it posible for all old backlinks created using https://myoldsite.co.uk to correctly forward?
2. By creating the 301 redirect, does this work at the domain level and http / https is not relevant when passing down all the SEO juice?

Thanks in advance,
Duncs

Comment: I feel like we're missing something here. You said the old site was hosted by Squarespace and the Domain name was provided by GoDaddy. But then you said that you want to the admin console of your old site to create a 301 redirect to your new site. Does this mean that when you closed the site on Squarespace, you transferred your old site to GoDaddy?

Comment: sorry, both domains are provided by GoDaddy and the old website was hosted by Squarespace. My new Wordpress site is hosted by SiteGround. When I mentioned the admin console, that was the GoDaddy Admin console where I managed the old domain and created the 301 redirect

Comment: From my understanding, GoDaddy does not redirect HTTPS request; only HTTP. In order to redirect HTTPS, you will need to have an actual site in which the SSL certificate for that domain is installed, and have that site redirect the request to a new site.

Comment: Ah ok. In which case, I will probably wait until my new site overtakes the old in the google rankings. Finger crossed this won't take months :)